# Wine uninstaller

Tags: wine, uninstall

I've uninstalled the wine programs using command `wine uninstaller` but i could still see the icons of the uninstalled programs.

How could I remove them?

Comment: The links of the programs are probably located in the `~/.wine/drive_c/users/<username>/Start Menu/Programs/<Program>` folder.

Answer (score -1):

You can search for these programs with Synaptic Package Manager

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

Search for the files there and remove them if you find them

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use synaptic to find the icon from an uninstalled wine program?